# loads all facets in multifacet in solrnet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr, solrnet

I've implemented multifacet in asp.net mvc based eCommerce application. In that, I do load specification filter using facet query with mincount=1.It loads all filters which are having mincount=0 on applying filter second time.

for example. In my mobile category,
First time , I exclude those filters which is having mincount=0

1. **Operating System** 
     Android(50) 
     Windows(8) 
     SPG(1)
2. **CardSlot** 
   microSD (328) 
   T-Flash (64)

after applying filter like OperatingSytem:SPG
It loads

1. **Operating System** 
     Android(50) 
     Windows(8) 
     SPG(1)  
     iOS(0)
2. **CardSlot** 
   microSD (50) 
   T-Flash (0) 
   Flash(0)

but It Should be

1. **Operating System** 
   Android(50) 
   Windows(8) 
   SPG(1)
2. **CardSlot** 
   microSD (50) 
   T-Flash (0)

I've implemented [Multi-Select Faceting and LocalParams](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams) 
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass `facet.mincount=1` every time you query Solr to be able to filter results with no results.
The best way to handle this is to add it to the defaults in request handler so that you don't have to pass it everytime.

Comment: if I pass facet.mincount=1 everytime, "T-Flash" from CardSlot will be disappear...But it should be there.

Comment: why should T-flash be shown and not Flash ? whats the use case ??

Comment: Because, the T-Flash is present in the category I'm filtering. Now consider having a Brand which is present in every category.. so with current use case, the first query will have only certain brands which is present in category.. but with Multi-Facet, it will list all categories.